# What is the different between KNeighborsRegressor and KNNImputer

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

What is the different between `KNeighborsRegressor` and `KNNImputer` ?

It seems that both methods used for imputation for filling in missing values using the k-Nearest Neighbors approach.

So what the different ?

when do we use `KNeighborsRegressor` or `KNNImputer` ?

Comment: As the names suggest, `KNNImputer` is used for imputation and `KNeighborsRegressor` is used for regression (prediction). And yes, both are based on KNN.

Comment: I saw examples in sklearn that we can use both methods for predict missing data

Comment: `KNeighborsRegressor` is used to predict response variables, whereas `KNNImputer` is used to replace missing values on feature variables.